# How to strip arguments from url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, filtering, query-string

I want to strip certain arguments from the URL.

Say for example:

The given url is `www.abc.com/def.php?xyz=pqr&efg=ijk` and I want to remove all the arguments where `xyz=<value>`, then the final url should look like `www.abc.com/def.php?efg=ijk`.

Currently, I am doing it in 3 traversals of the url.

```js
function(str) {
  if (str != null) return str.replace(/&?'(xyz|arg2|arg3)'=[^&#]*/g, '"'
    '"');
}

function(str) {
  if (str != null) return str.replace(/\\??&/, '"' ? '"');
}

function(str) {
  if (str != null) return str.replace(/\\?$/, '"'
    '"');
}
```

Can all 3 regexes be collapsed into a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work on my test cases:

([Javascript Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFablG/2))

Pattern: `/\?(?:xyz|arg2|arg3)=[^&#]*(?=$|#)|&(?:xyz|arg2|arg3)=[^&#]*|(?:xyz|arg2|arg3)=[^&#]*&/`

Effectively, it says:

1. Only match the `?` (start of querystring) if there is only one key-value pair in the query string.
2. Match the leading `&` with the key-value pair, if possible.
3. If not possible, match the trailing `&`

If you have a string that breaks this pattern, let me know and I'll try to fix it up.